# Software that can calculate PI to at least a thousand digits

Tags: math, calculator

I'm looking for software that can calculate `pi` (π).

I would like the software to meet these requirements,

- Simple as possible, something that just writes pi to either a text file or the command line.
- Actually calculates and finds pi as if it were doing it for the first time with just the software alone.
- Can calculate pi to at least a thousands digest without any problems.

Comment: Why you want to generate digits of `pi`? Is the point to *generate* or *use* those?

Comment: I want to use them.

Comment: If that question is phrased a bit differently ("Where can I find thousand digits of pi"), it could be off-topic for this site (IMO).

Comment: @Olli Yes. Thats why I didn't do it, this question is about which kind of answers are valid, not about if this kind of question is valid.

Comment: The best answer is [download a list](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/783). This shows that the question, as asked, is not really a software recommendation and does not fit on this site.

Comment: @Gilles I agree and would vote to close it (if it wasn't my question). I just wanted to create a sample question for the situation where "a website" would be a good answer.

Comment: If the question is to *calculate* digits of PI, then the best answer **is not** download a list (ignoring the comments from this thread). There might easily be reasons why it must be *calculated* instead of just downloaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to install any tool to calculate this. For example [this page](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/longnumPiMachin.htm) has JavaScript code that calculates an arbitrary number of pi decimals, up to 9999.

I validated it against [this Python program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9005163/592174), and it gave the same results. For some reason, it gives five additional digits, but those are on a separate line, so snipping it out is rather easy. Alternatively, just subtract 5 from the number of digits you want. Results are accurate, including those extra digits. This might depend on your browser, though (tested on Chrome on Android and Firefox on OS X).

Comment: Here's example of webapp (?) that answers the question, without installing a software. The question does not ask for installable software.

Comment: This clearly is a webapp (it keeps its use if you would run it on your own server) and a good answer to the question.

Comment: Considering the digits: intuitively, I think it has to do with the convergence of the algorithm. I.e, try with 5 and 10, and see that the tenth digit for PI(5) changes. Might be more severe for larger N.

Comment: @Bernhard that's true. However, it could just print proper number of digits even if it needs more for calculations.

Comment: Very good point :)

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer we're nicely drifting to meta discussion (which shouldn't happen here), but I truly think that "it keeps its use if you would run it on your own server" is not important at all for a good answer (if not required by the question, obviously).

Comment: @Bernhard I tried that up to 9999 digits (maximum that input field allows), and it was accurate, including those 5 additional digits. So it's not just for convergence of the algorithm.

Comment: If you're going to use something online, you might as well [download the result](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/783).

Comment: @Gilles Oh wow, getting back to discussion we had back in 2014 (see comments in the question). If the question specifically asks to **calculate** the value of the pi (for whatever reason, say, testing the performance of the computer), a good answer is not "download it from here".

Also, it's really important to remember that this specific question and answer were created to test the limits of softwarerecs, when that was still rather unclear.

Comment: @Olli This question was intended to test the limits of answers, but it fails at doing that because it isn't a good question.

Answer (score 5):

**[QuickPI](http://myownlittleworld.com/miscellaneous/computers/pilargetable.html)** is a Windows only command line tool that will generate pi to arbitrary length up to 256 million decimal places.  It will optionally write this output to a text file.

By entering this command:

```
qpi 1mi -fancy:100,100,1000000,,no, pi.txt
```

I was able to generate the following output:

```
QPI-QuickPi v4.0, (c) 2000-2005 S. Pagliarulo
Freely distributable, email: s_pagliarulo@hotmail.com

o AMD A4-3400 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics detected
o Processor speed measured at 2.70 GHz
o Single processor with dual cores
o 850.4 MB of memory available
o Using default training data

Computation of Pi to 1,000,000 digits
Method used : Chudnovsky
Started : Sun Feb 09 23:20:55 2014

Series size : 70514  (1,000,004 digits)
Series processing time : 1.07
Final value time : 0.20

Total time : 1.28 seconds
Total memory used : 12,263,030 (11.69 MB)
Processor utilization : 108.72%

Pi = 3.
1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679
8214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196
4428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273
7245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094
3305727036575959195309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912
....  remainder omitted for brevity
```

---

There is a wealth of other utilities to calculate pi  available [here](http://myownlittleworld.com/miscellaneous/computers/pilargetable.html).

The differ in their supported:

- platforms (mainly Windows and Linux binaries, some source)
- maximum decimal places (PiFast claims 12 billion)
- performance characteristics

Not having used any of these other utilities I am unable to comment on individual features.

Answer (score 3):

The symbolic and numeric calculation package Maxima appears capable of doing this rather easily.  This is an open source (GPL) software project, [available from Sourceforge](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/download.html).

I used the Xmaxima console for this result:

```
(%i1) bfloat(%pi),fpprec:1000; <enter>
(%o1) 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164\
062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081\
284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756\
482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245\
870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213\
841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931051185480744623799\
627495673518857527248912279381830119491298336733624406566430860213949463952247\
371907021798609437027705392171762931767523846748184676694051320005681271452635\
608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892\
589235420199561121290219608640344181598136297747713099605187072113499999983729\
780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881\
710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473035982534904287554687311595628\
63882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195909216420199b0
```

I can only vouch for the first thirty or so digits, personally.

To save the console output to a text file, use the menu item `Edit -> Save Console to File`.

Comment: I don't think Maxima fulfills "It needs to be as simple as possible"

Comment: @Olli: Are you perhaps thinking Maxima is not simple because of the many other things Maxima can do?  I assumed this task (find a thousand digits of pi) was meant to be representative of things one might want to do easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bc` for it:

```
scale=1000
4*a(1)
```

With `scale` you define how many digits `bc` should calculate, so setting this to `1000` gives 1000 digits (see [bc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#TOC5); by default it's set to `0`). And in fact: `22/7` shows `3`, but preceded by `scale=1000` it gives … well, I won't quote that :)

On Linux systems, this app usually goes by a package of the same name – and is part of most distributions. So depending on the Linux flavour used, `apt-get install bc` (or the corresponding `yum` etc. commands) should install it.

Comment: It should be noted that the last digit gets fudged but you can correct this by overcounting the scale and ignoring the last digit or you could use `sed` to remove the last digit: `echo "scale=1001; 4*a(1)" | bc -l | sed "s/.$//"`

Answer (score 1):

Please check: [Mini Pi](https://github.com/Mysticial/Mini-Pi) which can compute Pi to millions of digits.

However to calculate Pi, you don't need a software, as the algorytm can be written in one or few lines in almost any language.

- [Pi at Rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pi)
- [Calculate 500 digits of pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/506/11164) at CG
- [Pi Calculation Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22009/11164) at CG
- [Calculate π with quadratic convergence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47912/11164) at CG

therefore there are unlimited possibilities of such softwares.

In Linux Pi can be printed (not calculated) by the following one-line commands:

- `bc -l <<< "scale=1000; 4*a(1)"`
- `perl -Mbignum=bpi -wle 'print bpi(1000)'`

or check: [How do I print pi (3.14159)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/166220/21471) at Unix

Related:

- [Ooura's Mathematical Software Packages](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~ooura/)
- [Chronology of computation of π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_computation_of_%CF%80) at wiki

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to use a tool to calculate this, you can just visit this website and copy as many digits as you like:

http://www.piday.org/million/

**Important beta notice**: This answer is a sample for [this meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/can-i-answer-with-website-webapp).

Please don't fix it, either a link to a website is a valid answer (then its good this way), or not (then we should downvote it).

Comment: This does not answer the question (at least not the title), which says "Tool to calculate". It's different thing to calculate or to just have something.

Comment: So I have to figure where the thousandth digit is and copy from there? Not really an ideal solution.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables if you read that [linked](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/255/can-i-answer-with-website-webapp) meta question, you'll find interesting discussion of whether it must be "software package" or not. Forbidding all webapps is crazy, and we're trying to define what is allowed and what is not. But you're right that it does not answer the question very well.

Comment: @olli yeah, was in the process of editing my comment, didn't see the tiny disclaimer  font on my phone.

Comment: @Olli The easiest way to perform a calculation is to know the result! This is the best answer on this thread.

Comment: @Gilles Please, don't hijack this answer. I know that its short myself. We should close this Question as soon as the corresponding meta is done.

Comment: @Gilles: no, that is not correct. This answer does not answer the question (ignoring comments). If the question is "Tool to calculate PI to a thousand digits", then it definitely is software recommendation question. Even if there's a shortcut, it still is. "Is there a tool to simulate this problem?" -> "Take this dataset" is not proper answer. There might easily be reasons why *calculating* it is important instead of just obtaining the results.

Comment: The request is “I want to have pi to a thousand digits”. So ok, technically the answer should say: use your web browser's “save as” function to store the result in a file.

Comment: So, any question that asks for a tool but can be interpreted as "you want to have some data" is off-topic, because valid answer could be "download this dataset"? Or is it just that you didn't read the question in detail. "Tool to **calculate** PI to a thousand digits" (emphasis mine). And this is pretty stupid discussion as @AngeloNeuschitzer already said, this one is to clarify that meta discussion, not to have high-quality question. But similar issues will come up again later on.

Comment: `Please don't fix it, either a link to a website is a valid answer (then its good this way), or not (then we should downvote it).`  That's a pretty black-or-white view.  I downvoted because, regardless of whether link-only answers are valid or not, ***this*** answer is extremely sub-par.  If you're trying to test the theory of websites as answers, at least make sure the answer is good.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables But I don't think that websites as answers CAN be good. Thats my whole point.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to at least post a link to a website that would actually be *helpful* to your question, and let a *good* answer stand on its own merits, as opposed to a terrible answer?

Comment: The linked site is helpful to the question. I'm all yours if you can do better.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer remember that by giving intentionally *bad* website/webapp answer, you're not proving anything related to that meta question.

Comment: @Olli it was the best I could come up with. I'm all ears for better examples.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18285)

Comment: @Tom et al. As explained in the meta thread linked in the answer, this *is* a valid answer to the question as asked. (Whether the question is valid on this site is a different issue.)

Comment: @Gilles My apologies, someone flagged it and I saw a website and jumped the gun on this one, I'll be sure to run a meta check before flags again.