# A number cruncher software that can work with very large numbers

Tags: math, scientific-computing, numerical-analysis

I am looking for a software that is able to crunch very large numbers, i.e. numbers exceeding 100 (or thousands of) digits. It needs to be able to perform basic operations on them as well as others such as taking the n-th root, finding the nearest prime, etc.

Any good recommendations?

Comment: also see this as well https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/782/25291 `Software that can calculate PI to at least a thousand digits`

Comment: @TedTaylorofLife I already checked that out, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you look at **Wolfram Mathematica** as @john suggested.

The only thing is that John should not state something he does not know.

> There are other commercial packages such as Mathematica and Matlab that
>   may be able to do that but they are more than $1000 I think. Expensive
>   anyway.

1. First off, pricing is dependent on intention of use. More use = more money.
2. Do you honestly think you will get the same amount of precision with a $25 dollar software package as with a software that is maintained by hundreds of part-time mathematicians? It definitely is possible, but extremely unlikely.
   [Pricing for Mathematica Licensing by Industry](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/pricing/)

## Pricing Information Based off of Use

[image: Home and Hobby Mathematica License]

[image: Industry Pricing Wolfram Mathematica License]

## Example of Using Wolfram Language for Precision with Very Large Numbers

[image: Wolfram Precision Software]

Comment: @karel Interesting. Thanks for the edits and useful information. I did not know that.  In terms of format, were you viewing this on mobile or desktop?

Comment: I ended up purchasing Mathematica and it is everything I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

A quick check with python3.6 64 bit:

```
In [13]: n = 1234*10**40000

In [14]: len(str(n))
Out[14]: 40004

In [15]: m = n + 1

In [16]: m-n
Out[16]: 1
```

If you need really big integer numbers with no loss of accuracy you can use python under jupyter, (this gets round the command prompt memory limitations by working in a browser).

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Mac I would try Math Studio. Python with its Numpy module works well on any platform. Python will do integer math to however many digits you want limited by computer memory. Python is of course free while Math Studio costs around $25. There are other commercial packages such as Mathmatica and Matlab that may be able to do that but they are more than $1000 I think. Expensive anyway. A final option I'm aware of is Sage Math. An online mathematics package that does quite a lot. Built out of python and other packages such as Maxima. Maxima maybe an option as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But does Matlab and Mathematica work well with integers with over 100 or even 1000 (10k) digits?

Comment: That I don't know. Sorry...

Comment: Both are popular packages. Their respective web pages may answer your question.